# Php line graph by using GD and MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, gd

I'm trying to draw a simple line graph which would use values from the database. At the moment I have a function which gets my data as it should and I also have another `.php` file which should be the one where the image is constructed.

I've basically used the example from [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpgd/About-linegraph.html) and it works if the values are typed manually. Nevertheless when I try to call `$arrval = functionToGetValues("$keyword");` it just won't work it won't draw anything. I'm guessing it's mostly because the `GD` is so messed up because it doesn't seem to work too good even with normal php commands.

I think it's unnecessary to post exact code because `functionToGetValues` works and it just returns an array of values.

I also tried to play with scopes like initializing the `$arrvals` in `functionToGetValues()` but it didn't work. My calling sequence was:

/main.php

```
include "conn.php";

....

dbquery("$keyword");

//in dbquery($keyword)...

$arrval = array(...);

for($i=1; $i<30;$i++)
{
     $sql =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%$keyword%'") or die("Query error: ". mysql_error());;
     $total = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$arrval [$i] = $total;

}

<img src='imgdraw.php?keyword=$keyword'vspace='50'/>";
```

I also tried [this](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial//gd-linegp.php) type of solution but the include "conn.php" just doesn't seem to work with GD -_-. I can't find out the reason :(

Comment: Not an answer but you don't have to encapsulate the `$keywords` in `functionToGetValues("$keyword");` with quotes. Same goes for `query("$keyword")`

Comment: You also have two semi colons after `mysql_error());;`

Comment: And you have a syntax error `<img src='imgdraw.php?keyword=$keyword'vspace='50'/>";`

Comment: Oh thanks, it has been a couple of years since I wrote php so the syntax is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have much luck with GD You could use google's chart tools for generating graphs.  I have always found it easy to use and well documented and the graphs it generates look pretty good.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

You would query your database then build up an array before exporting it inside a javascript tag with the a php array with `echo json_decode();`

Comment: Oh that looks way much better, I have to give it a try!

Comment: Or could I just use PHP for a POST Request as http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/post_requests.html modifying just $chd .= $data . ','; seems to be easier but I don't know is it better way or anything.